# Open FIle Python tkinter - problem with message box when introduced new input

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

### Self Introduction

Hi, Im making a basic notepad with tkinter and I have 0 to no knoledge when it comes to coding, I'm not a programmer but I do enjoy seeing some code.

### Current Project state

At the moment I have coded basic structure for, new_file, open_file, save_file, save_as_file and exit function, I have 2 main bugs both of them encountered in open_file().

### Introduction to problem

I have a global url that stores the names of the files and one save flag that happens when i save the file. "untitled" to "open_file" works like intended, whoever, the main issue occurs when I type something new to the file.

### Current Goal

My goal here is to create a simple functional notepad ---> when I open_file and open another one without typing anything it wont ask me if I want to save file, If I open one file, type and proceed to open another file with will send me a pop up message asking me if I want to save changes, same to when I exit file.

### My Bugs

One of the bugs happens when I click "save_file", at the moment, everytime I click "open file" it will ask me if I want to save file no mather what I do, but as soon as I click save in one of the documents and open another file it won't ask me if I want to save anymore.

It happens because of this line of code

elif save_flag:
open_file_function()

Second "bug" is that there is no way to check if new input was added to the document so it can ask me if I want to save document

### Global Variable

```
 #variable
 url = ''
 save_flag = False
```

### Open_file

```
def open_file(e=None):
    text = text_editor.get('1.0', END)
    # If Nothing is written then directly exit.
    if len(text) == 1:
        open_file_function()
    elif save_flag:
        open_file_function()
    else:
        choice = askyesnocancel('Notepad', 'Do you want to save your changes to ' + main_application.title()
                                + '?')
        if choice:
            save_file()
            open_file_function()
        elif choice is None:
            pass
        else:
            open_file_function()


def open_file_function():
    global url

    url = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="\Desktop", title='Select File',
                                     filetypes=(
                                     ('Text File', '*.txt'), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("HTML Files", "*.html"),
                                     ('All files', '*.*')))
    try:
        with open(url, 'r') as fr:
            text_editor.delete(1.0, tk.END)
            text_editor.insert(1.0, fr.read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return
    except:
        return
    main_application.title(os.path.basename(url))

    name = url
    name = pathlib.Path(name).name
    main_application.title(f'{name} - NotePad')
```

### Save_file and Save_as_file

```
def save_file(e=None):
    global url
    global save_flag

    if url:
        # Save the file
        text_file = open(url, 'w')
        text_file.write(text_editor.get(1.0, END))
        # Close the file
        text_file.close()
        # Put status update or popup code
        name = url
        name = pathlib.Path(name).name
        main_application.title(f'{name} - NotePad')
        save_flag = True
    else:
        save_as_file()


def save_as_file(e=None):
    global url

    url = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="\Desktop", title="Save As", defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(
        ("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("HTML Files", "*.html")))
    if url:
        # Update Status Bars
        name = url
        name = pathlib.Path(name).name
        main_application.title(f'{name} - NotePad')
        take_file = open(url, "w")
        take_text = text_editor.get(1.0, END)
        take_file.write(take_text)
        take_file.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("Successfully Saved", "Your file saved successfully")
```

### Exit_funtion

```
def exit_application():
    text = text_editor.get('1.0', END)
    # If Nothing is written then directly exit.
    if len(text) == 1:
        main_application.destroy()
    # Else check whether it has saved if yes then exit else prompt to save it.
    elif save_flag:
        main_application.destroy()

    else:
        choice = askyesnocancel('Notepad', 'Do you want to save your changes to ' + main_application.title()
                                + '?')
        if choice:
            save_file()
            main_application.destroy()
        elif choice is None:
            pass
        else:
            main_application.destroy()
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you set `save_flag = True` in `save_file` but you forgot it in `save_as_file`. And I don't see `save_flag = False` in any function. You should set it when you press any key in widget. And this may need `text_editor.bind("<key>", function_name)` and in `function_name()` you should set `save_flag = False`

Comment: as for me you have problems with `messagebox` only because you forgot ti set `save_flag = True` and `save_flag = False` in some places.

Comment: I did had it in save as file but I though it might be redundant to have it there but you are totaly right! About the bind funcion its giving me this error:

Comment: File "...", line 264, in <module>
    text_editor.bind("<key>", function_name)

File "...", line 1421, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
 

File "...", line 1375, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "key"

Comment: sorry, it has to be `"<Key>"` with upper `K`

Comment: HOLYYYY IS FUNCTIONAL!! so basically instead of asking you everything I made some research aswell in the functional code I added an event and glovla save_file because without the event it gives me an "takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" ---> def function_name(event):
    global save_flag

    save_flag = False

Comment: besides that added a     global save_flag
    save_flag = True to open file funcition and its working like a charm